# How to solve a Null Pointer Exception caused by an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have encountered an error after adding a third activity to my code. The code generating the error is the following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIncomeIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Add_Income.class);
            startActivityForResult(callIncomeIntent, 0);
        }
    });
```

Generates error :

```
11-18 13:59:29.137: D/libEGL(13211): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
11-18 13:59:29.147: D/libEGL(13211): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
11-18 13:59:29.147: D/libEGL(13211): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
11-18 13:59:29.157: I/Adreno-EGL(13211): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL4169980)
11-18 13:59:29.157: I/Adreno-EGL(13211): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
11-18 13:59:29.157: I/Adreno-EGL(13211): Build Date: 11/04/13 Mon
11-18 13:59:29.157: I/Adreno-EGL(13211): Local Branch: 
11-18 13:59:29.157: I/Adreno-EGL(13211): Remote Branch: 
11-18 13:59:29.157: I/Adreno-EGL(13211): Local Patches: 
11-18 13:59:29.157: I/Adreno-EGL(13211): Reconstruct Branch: 
11-18 13:59:29.197: D/OpenGLRenderer(13211): Enabling debug mode 0
11-18 13:59:31.800: D/AndroidRuntime(13211): Shutting down VM
11-18 13:59:31.800: W/dalvikvm(13211): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415b58b0)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tei.ptix.income_management/tei.ptix.income_management.Add_Income}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at tei.ptix.income_management.Add_Income.onCreate(Add_Income.java:31)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    ... 11 more
```

When I hover mouse over Intent it gives the following text:
android.content.Intent.Intent(Context packageContext, Class
Note: This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc.

Can someone please suggest a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is in the Add_Income activity so you will need to post the initial methods for that class too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-18 13:59:31.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13211):    at tei.ptix.income_management.Add_Income.onCreate(Add_Income.java:31)
```

Somebody wrote a Java class named `tei.ptix.income_management.Add_Income`. From your code snippet above, it would appear to be a subclass of `Activity`. In its `onCreate()` method, in line 31 of `Add_Income.java`, you have a `NullPointerException`.

So, take a look at line 31 of `Add_Income.java` and determine why you are calling a method on some parameter, variable, or data member that is `null`. If you cannot determine why it is `null`, perhaps consider asking a question where you provide the source code to the activity, or at least the `onCreate()` method, where you point out which line is line 31, and somebody may be able to help you identify what is `null` and why.